# Matrices entre clases Java

Tags: java, matrices

Tengo una pregunta como le harían para usar una matriz en varias clases, mi problema surge que tengo que crear botones en java pero dentro de ellos no puedo crear metodos.

```
        modificacion_Usuario.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //aqui trabajaria la matriz, pero no me deja llamar metodos.
        }
    });
```

Comment: Agrega algo mas de código, aunque no compile, que exactamente intentas pero no puedes hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Crea los métodos fuera de los métodos de los botones y después llamas los métodos dentro del métodos del método del botón.

```
modificacion_Usuario.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    algunMetodo();
    }
}); 
void algunMetodo(){
// codigo
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero evitamos contestar que no cumplan con [mcve]